# Problems with the N queen homework exercice in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

- I'm using my own implementation of the stack.
- I should not use recursion.

My code:

```
public static void solve(int bsize)
{
    stack queenLoc = new stack();

    int y=0;
    int count=0;
    boolean done = false;


    while(done == false && queenLoc.size() != bsize)    
    {
        queenLoc.push(count);

        if(!isSafe(bsize,queenLoc,count))
        {
            while(queenLoc.getTop() == bsize)
            {
                y = queenLoc.pop();
                count--;
            }
            if(queenLoc.top != null)
            {
                queenLoc.push(queenLoc.pop()+1);
                count++;        
            }
            else
            {
                queenLoc.push(y+1);
                count++;
            }
        }
        else if(queenLoc.size() == bsize)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            queenLoc.push(count);
        }
    }

    queenLoc.showAll();

    if(queenLoc.size() == bsize)
        printBoard(bsize, queenLoc);
}

public static boolean isSafe(int bsize, stack s,int count)
{               
    for(int i = 1; i<s.size(); i++)
    {
            if(s.getTop() == s.get(i) || s.getTop()+count == s.get(i)+s.size() || s.getTop()-count == s.get(i)-s.size())
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure what is really going on, i'm getting wrong position and the printBoard function is only printing the queens on the first row.
I actually tried a lot of possibilities, but i got a bit confused.

Can anyone just point me out to the right direction and tell me where's the problem in my code. I am using the stack to store the column and the "count" variable in the stack class to point me to which row.

Comment: I recommend you first write and debug a recursive solution, and then convert it to using stack. The best treatment of the 8-queen problem that I've seen over the years remains that by Dijkstra (starting on page 72 [of this book](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/programmiersprachen/artikel/EWD-notes-structured.pdf)). Don't get too creative too early: it is easier to optimize a debugged solution than to debug an optimized solution.

Comment: Please consider following [java naming conventions](http://www.javaranch.com/style.jsp) - like first letter of your class name in UPPER case. It will be useful especially in scenarios like this, where you are looking at a fragment.

Comment: @ringbearer thanks for the link, i usually capitalize the first letter of the class name, not sure why i didnt pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
package mynqueens;


public class MyNQueens {
public static int board[][] = new int[4][4];
public static int row,column;

    public MyNQueens(){


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    check(0,0);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
    public static void check(int i, int j ){

        while(i<3){
            board[i][j] = 1;
            i++;
        }
        while(i!=0){
            board[i][j] = 1;

            i--;
        }
        while(j<3){
            board[i][j]=1;
            j++;
        }
        while(j!=0){
            board[i][j] = 1;
            j--;
        }
        while(j<3 || i<3){
            board[i][j] = 1;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        while(j!=0 || i!=0){
            board[i][j] = 1;
            i--;
            j--;
        }
        while(i<3 || j!=0){
            board[i][j]=1;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        while(i!=0 || j<3){
         board[i][j]=1;
         i--;
         j++;

        }


    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start erasing elements in inner while section

```
while(queenLoc.getTop() == bsize)
{
    y = queenLoc.pop();
    count--;
}
```

number of elements in queenStack will exceed bsize.

You have `while(done == false && queenLoc.size() != bsize)` so when size of queenLoc will be equal to bsize you will print result.

What I am saying is that after `bsize` steps you are always printing results.

Advise: Your code should have invariant "queenLoc represents position where no two queens attack each other".

Comment: aha you are right, i did as you said right now but i got stuck into a boot loop. I think the problem is in the isSafe function but not sure what's causing it...

Comment: The problem is i really got confused a lot, i'm sure still where's the problem in my code.

Comment: Then try changing isSafe so you could be sure. For example for each queen calculate their exact location on a chessboard. Then checking if queen at (x1, y1) attacks queen at (x2, y2) is fairly simple `x1 == x2 || y1 == y2 || Math.abs(x1-x2) == Math.abs(y1-y2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Manimekalai
 */
public class Queen {


    public static boolean isConsistent(int[] q, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (q[i] == q[n])             return false;   // same column
            if ((q[i] - q[n]) == (n - i)) return false;   // same major diagonal
            if ((q[n] - q[i]) == (n - i)) return false;   // same minor diagonal
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void printQueens(int[] q)
    {
        int N = q.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (q[i] == j) System.out.print("Q ");
                else           System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



    public static void enumerate(int N)
    {
        int[] a = new int[N];
        enumerate(a, 0);
    }

    public static void enumerate(int[] q, int n)
    {
        int N = q.length;
        if (n == N) printQueens(q);
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                q[n] = i;
                if (isConsistent(q, n)) enumerate(q, n+1);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Enter N value");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int N=s.nextInt();
        enumerate(N);
    }
}
```